# Install SQlite3 on os x

Tags: macos, sqlite

Trying to install symfony2 and I get the following message

> You need to enable either the SQLite3 or PDO_SQLite extension for the
>   profiler to run properly

I installed it via macports

```
$ sudo port install sqlite3
Password:
Warning: port definitions are more than two weeks old, consider using selfupdate
--->  Computing dependencies for sqlite3
--->  Deactivating sqlite3 @3.7.1_0+universal
--->  Cleaning sqlite3
--->  Activating sqlite3 @3.7.1_0
--->  Cleaning sqlite3
imac27:bin ed_lea$ sudo apachectl graceful
```

check that it exists

```
$ which sqlite3
/opt/local/bin/sqlite3
```

and it's in my path

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.1
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
```

but I'm **still getting the same error**.

I guess PHP is not able to see it but I don't know how to add it. I'm not using the default version of PHP that came with os x. Here's a link to my php.ini file (large image) http://cl.ly/2J2X0A0n1W2R1T0x3f30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try run corresponding port installation like [here](http://azhari.harahap.us/2011/05/from-xampp-to-npsf-nginx-php-sqlite3-fastcgi/)?

Comment: prefect, running "sudo port install php5-sqlite" did it, thanks.